# How to connect storyboard to code

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, storyboard, xib

I created empty IOS project and want to create UI. I searched for information about connecting storyboard to code but there is nothing about it, just about xib files. So is it possible to use storyboard instead xib in empty project? And how?

Comment: New File > Storyboard.

Comment: Not that. How can I get access to storyboard from code?

Comment: No. Its simple. Add a new Storyboard file. Call it Main.storyboard. In your project settings, set it as the main storyboard.

Comment: See me answer. I've added a picture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First create an empty project with some class name [image]

then create an storyboard from file->userInterface->storyboard

[image]

then give a name for the storyboard after that press storyboard in the left menu and place a viewcontroller and hold viewcontroller give class name as already created Uiviewcontrollerclass [image]

[image]

finally press project choose main interface as ViewController.storyboard

if you wanna code suppose segue use [self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"nameofcontroller" sender: self];

if don want segue go like this

[self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"TheSequeName" sender: self];
The @"TheSequeName" is defined when you ctrl drag a button to open a new view controller on the storyboard

If you don't use segue, there are many variants to open a new view controller. The basic one is using a separate NIB (without storyboard)

```
SecondViewController *view = [[SecondViewController allow] initWithNibName:@"NibName" bundle:nil];
```

If you declare your view controller on Storyboard, you can use

```
viewController *view = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"viewStoryboardId"]; 
Then you show your viewController using navigation controller

[self.navigationController pushViewController:view animated:YES];
```

Hope it works

Answer (score 5):

You can get the storyboard object like this assuming you have a Storyboard file already in the Project

```
    UIStoryboard *storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPhone" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    YourViewController *yourVC = [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"identifier"];
    //Do whatever with the viewcontroller object
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:yourVC animated:YES ];
```

Note:

1. Check the Storyboard name
2. Check your viewcontroller identifier in the Storyboard

[image]

Comment: Yes. I tried this. But it doesnt see storyboard. When I created storyboard I called it "enter" http://bit.ly/1fVrsFH and called view contrioller as "myViewController" http://bit.ly/1aiDVzl.

Comment: @LongSmith - Set it as the main interface file. That might help. Look at my answer.

Comment: @LongSmith just check my image. Confirm that you have given the identifier as such.

Answer (score 0):

From the 'File' menu, create a new `Storyboard`.

Call it `Main.storyboard`.

In your project settings, set it as the main interface file under the Deployment Info.

[image]

Comment: This is just telling them how to create a new storyboard - how does it answer the question on how to connect them in the code?

Comment: Handling Storyboards via code is more practical if there are multiple Storyboards. This is a better, clearer, more understandable approach, in my opinion.

Comment: Your answer just tells someone how to create a new storyboard not how to use it with code. Answers should be based on facts not opinions. This answer could be good but it lacks detail and doesn't answer the question that has been asked.

Comment: We're talking about different **approaches** here. Opinions define approaches. I'm not saying that iPrabu's answer is wrong. Feel free to go with whatever you like.

Comment: This still doesn't answer the question that has been asked though.

Comment: Of course it does. He can now add `UIViewControllers` to the `Storyboard`, access them via the code. I mean, isn't what you do after this kind of self-explanatory ?

Comment: If it was they wouldn't be asking would they.

Comment: @SanjeetSuhag it might work for him but it still doesn't actually answer the question asked. All it means is that the OP failed to make it clear that it was how to create a storyboard not how to link a storyboard with code.

Answer (score 0):

```
New File - > Objective-C Class (of type View Controller) -> without Xib file
```

now on on storyboard, go to that particular xib file

```
in property window -> Show Identity Inspector -> change class to above added ViewController.
```

That's it, now you can control your storyboard xib files from code.

Comment: This is just telling them how to create a new storyboard - how does it answer the question on how to connect them in the code?

Comment: How to control xib I know. Interested in control storyboard.